# How to align a header with a toolbar using Twitter Bootstrap and a list-inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm tring to make a little toolbar right next to a header. So I thought list-inline ought to work pretty well. And it works, but the alignment is off and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<ul class="list-inline">
<li><h3>Editor</h3> </li>
<li><div class="btn-toolbar editor toolbar" role="toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">other</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yhaJG/1/

Comment: How did you want it to be aligned?

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS might be what you're looking for. Hard to tell exactly what you want from the question though.

```
.list-inline { margin-top: 5px; }
.list-inline li { vertical-align: top; }
.list-inline h3 { margin-top: 6px }
```

Just adjust the `margin-top` values as needed.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yhaJG/7/

Also, you might want to add another class to the `ul` element and apply the styles to that. You can still leave `list-inline` on the `ul` element, but that way these styles won't be applied to every `list-inline` since there may be other uses for inline lists on your site.